# Creating custom Text Selection actions in a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, action-process-text

I want to transmit the text selected in an other app to my Flutter app.

e.g. I am reading a page on a website, an ebook reader or some text in an other application, I select a piece of text from the app and I send it to my app by clicking on a custom element from the context menu which appears after selecting it.

In many sources I found that this is possible to be done in Android by using ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT But the problem is that I have no idea about how to integrate and use this feature in my app.

I found and installed [Intent](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/intent) Package which pretends to be able to add this functionality ([here](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/intent/latest/action/Action/ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT-constant.html) they write that they support it)

In the image below you can see in the context menu "Web Search" and "Search Wikipedia" - what I want is to be able to add "My App Action" which will open my Flutter app and do some staff with the selected text.

[image]

The code of my current `main.dart` app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intent/intent.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'My Words'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

P.S. I just started learning Flutter and Mobile App development, so please do not judge me hard.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a plugin to implement this.

Please check out: [action_process_text Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/action_process_text) .

First, include it in your project.

```yaml
dependencies:
  action_process_text: <latest version>
```

Run pub get and get packages.

Add this to `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `android\app\src\main\` folder.

```xml
 <activity android:name="com.example.action_process_text.ActionProcessTextPlugin"
            android:label="Action_Text" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Change the `android:label` from `Action_Text` to the action text that you want to display.

Then import the package to use it.

```dart
import 'package:action_process_text/action_process_text.dart';
```

Now, use the constructor of the widget to initialize the action_process_text. `ActionProcessText.getInputText` is used to get the selected text from the android action.

**Example snippet:**

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  _MainPageState() {
    initActionProcessText();
  }

  Future<void> initActionProcessText() async {
    inputText = await ActionProcessText.getInputText;
    setState(() {});
  }

  String inputText = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
  }
```

And check out my article on this plugin at: [Article on action_process_text](https://medium.com/@coder_with_a_bushido/adding-text-selection-action-in-android-for-flutter-apps-d107c5d4c5ae?source=friends_link&sk=ed13c797f8343cedf188f87b5b1db286) .

Please support this package by letting fellow flutter developers know about it and feel free to open issues/bugs and PRs on my github repo: [action_process_text Source](https://github.com/coder-with-a-bushido/ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT-Flutter) .

Comment: Is death???????

Answer (score -1):

Check out the SelectableText widget and its toolbarOptions property.

From a quick look, if the action you need is not provided, navigate to the EditableText class which SelectableText uses to display the toolbar options.  A comment here specifies this is where you can implement your own action:

"[EditableText] and its derived widgets have their own default [ToolbarOptions].
Create a custom [ToolbarOptions] if you want explicit control over the toolbar
option."

Hope this helps! I'm still learning as well :)

Comment: What you explained here might make sense for the text selected inside the Flutter application. But what I need is to be able to add this custom action for the text selected in any application, e.g. a website, an ebook reader, etc.

Comment: Oh my mistake I misread your question. Currently I'm not sure but I'll post back if I come across a solution.